# Logistic Regression: Scikit Learn vs Statsmodels

Tags: regression, logistic, python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I am trying to understand why the output from logistic regression of these
two libraries gives different results.

I am using the dataset from UCLA idre [tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/), predicting `admit` based
on `gre`, `gpa` and `rank`. `rank` is treated as categorical variable, so it
is first converted to dummy variable with `rank_1` dropped. An intercept
column is also added.

```
py
from patsy import dmatrices
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
y, X = dmatrices('admit ~ gre + gpa + C(rank)', df, return_type = 'dataframe')
X.head()
>  Intercept  C(rank)[T.2]  C(rank)[T.3]  C(rank)[T.4]  gre   gpa
0          1             0             1             0  380  3.61
1          1             0             1             0  660  3.67
2          1             0             0             0  800  4.00
3          1             0             0             1  640  3.19
4          1             0             0             1  520  2.93

# Output from scikit-learn
model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = False)
mdl = model.fit(X, y)
model.coef_
> array([[-1.35417783, -0.71628751, -1.26038726, -1.49762706,  0.00169198,
     0.13992661]]) 
# corresponding to predictors [Intercept, rank_2, rank_3, rank_4, gre, gpa]

# Output from statsmodels
logit = sm.Logit(y, X)
logit.fit().params
> Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: 0.573147
     Iterations 6
Intercept      -3.989979
C(rank)[T.2]   -0.675443
C(rank)[T.3]   -1.340204
C(rank)[T.4]   -1.551464
gre             0.002264
gpa             0.804038
dtype: float64
```

The output from `statsmodels` is the same as shown on the idre website, but I
am not sure why scikit-learn produces a different set of coefficients. Does
it minimize some different loss function? Is there any documentation that
states the implementation?

Comment: The results with leaving the constant term out won't reproduce the Scikit results either, since I checked it. It must be the regularization.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your clue to figuring this out should be that the parameter estimates from the scikit-learn estimation are uniformly smaller in magnitude than the statsmodels counterpart. This might lead you to believe that scikit-learn applies some kind of parameter regularization. You can confirm this by reading the [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

There is no way to switch off regularization in scikit-learn, but you can make it ineffective by setting the tuning parameter `C` to a large number. Here is how that works in your case:

```
# module imports
from patsy import dmatrices
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model as sm

# read in the data & create matrices
df = pd.read_csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
y, X = dmatrices('admit ~ gre + gpa + C(rank)', df, return_type = 'dataframe')

# sklearn output
model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = False, C = 1e9)
mdl = model.fit(X, y)
model.coef_

# sm
logit = sm.Logit(y, X)
logit.fit().params
```

**UPDATE**: As correctly pointed out in the comments below, now you can switch off the relularization in scikit-learn by setting `penalty='none'` (see the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! With this regularized result, I was  trying to duplicate the result using the `glmnet` package in R, but could not get the same coefficient. [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet_beta.html#log) has a slightly different cost function comparing to [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression), but even if I set `alpha=0` in `glmnet` (meaning only use l2-penalty) and set `1/(N*lambda)=C`, I still do not get the same result?

Comment: My intuition is that if I divide both terms of the cost function in `glmnet` by `lambda` and set the new constant in font of the log-likelihood, which is `1/(N*lambda)` equal to that in `sklearn`, the two cost functions become identical, or am I missing something?

Comment: @hurrikale Ask a new question and link it here, and I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks! I posted the question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203816/logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-glmnet).

Comment: I think the best way to switch off the regularization in scikit-learn is by setting `penalty='none'`.

Comment: As Nzbuu points out, the newest version of sklearn finally does allow to completely switch off regularization.

Comment: Now above-mentioned dataset could be found at <https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv>

Comment: Does the addition of `penalty='none'` mean that the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression) is outdated, since it only mentions the "setting C to a very high value" way of switching off regularization?

Answer (score 10):

What tripped me up:

- disable sklearn regularization `LogisticRegression(C=1e9)`
- add statsmodels intercept `sm.Logit(y, sm.add_constant(X))` OR disable sklearn intercept `LogisticRegression(C=1e9, fit_intercept=False)`
- sklearn returns probability for each class so `model_sklearn.predict_proba(X)[:, 1] == model_statsmodel.predict(X)`
- use of predict function `model_sklearn.predict(X) == (model_statsmodel.predict(X) > 0.5).astype(int)`

I'm now seeing the same results in both libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Another difference is that you've set fit_intercept=False, which effectively is a different model. You can see that Statsmodel includes the intercept. Not having an intercept surely changes the expected weights on the features. Try the following and see how it compares:

`model = LogisticRegression(C=1e9)`

Comment: It is the exact opposite actually - statsmodels does *not* include the intercept by default. See the SO threads [Coefficients for Logistic Regression scikit-learn vs statsmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005911/coefficients-for-logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels) and [scikit-learn & statsmodels - which R-squared is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614157/scikit-learn-statsmodels-which-r-squared-is-correct), as well as the answer below.

Comment: @desertnaut you're right statsmodels doesn't include the intercept by default. Here the design matrix `X` returned by `dmatrices` includes a constant column of 1's (see output of `X.head()`). Then even though both the scikit and statsmodels estimators are fit with no explicit instruction for an intercept (the former through `intercept=False`, the latter by default) both models effectively have an intercept, which can be seen by inspecting the outputs carefully.