# Logistic Regression: Scikit Learn vs glmnet

Tags: r, logistic, python, scikit-learn, glmnet

I am trying to duplicate the results from `sklearn` logistic regression library using `glmnet` package in R.

From the `sklearn` logistic regression [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression), it is trying to minimize the cost function under l2 penalty
$$\min_{w,c} \frac12 w^Tw + C\sum_{i=1}^N \log(\exp(-y_i(X_i^Tw+c)) + 1)$$

From the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet_beta.html#log) of `glmnet`, its implementation minimizes a slightly different cost function
$$\min_{\beta, \beta_0} -\left[\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N y_i(\beta_0+x_i^T\beta)-\log(1+e^{(\beta_0+x_i^T\beta)})\right] + \lambda[(\alpha-1)||\beta||_2^2/2+\alpha||\beta||_1]$$

With some tweak in the second equation, and by setting $\alpha=0$, $$\lambda\min_{\beta, \beta_0} \frac1{N\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^N \left[-y_i(\beta_0+x_i^T\beta)+\log(1+e^{(\beta_0+x_i^T\beta)})\right] + ||\beta||_2^2/2$$

which differs from `sklearn` cost function only by a factor of $\lambda$ if set $\frac1{N\lambda}=C$, so I was expecting the same coefficient estimation from the two packages. But they are different. I am using the dataset from UCLA idre [tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/), predicting `admit` based on `gre`, `gpa` and `rank`. There are 400 observations, so with $C=1$, $\lambda = 0.0025$.

```
#python sklearn
df = pd.read_csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
y, X = dmatrices('admit ~ gre + gpa + C(rank)', df, return_type = 'dataframe')
X.head()
>  Intercept  C(rank)[T.2]  C(rank)[T.3]  C(rank)[T.4]  gre   gpa
0          1             0             1             0  380  3.61
1          1             0             1             0  660  3.67
2          1             0             0             0  800  4.00
3          1             0             0             1  640  3.19
4          1             0             0             1  520  2.93

model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = False, C = 1)
mdl = model.fit(X, y)
model.coef_
> array([[-1.35417783, -0.71628751, -1.26038726, -1.49762706,  0.00169198,
     0.13992661]]) 
# corresponding to predictors [Intercept, rank_2, rank_3, rank_4, gre, gpa]


> # R glmnet
> df = fread("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
> X = as.matrix(model.matrix(admit~gre+gpa+as.factor(rank), data=df))[,2:6]
> y = df[, admit]
> mylogit <- glmnet(X, y, family = "binomial", alpha = 0)
> coef(mylogit, s = 0.0025)
6 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                    1
(Intercept)      -3.984226893
gre               0.002216795
gpa               0.772048342
as.factor(rank)2 -0.530731081
as.factor(rank)3 -1.164306231
as.factor(rank)4 -1.354160642
```

The `R` output is somehow close to logistic regression without regularization, as can be seen [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203740/logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels). Am I missing something or doing something obviously wrong?

Update: I also tried to use `LiblineaR` package in `R` to conduct the same process, and yet got another different set of estimates (`liblinear` is also the solver in `sklearn`):

```
> fit = LiblineaR(X, y, type = 0, cost = 1)
> print(fit)
$TypeDetail
[1] "L2-regularized logistic regression primal (L2R_LR)"
$Type
[1] 0
$W
            gre          gpa as.factor(rank)2 as.factor(rank)3 as.factor(rank)4         Bias
[1,] 0.00113215 7.321421e-06     5.354841e-07     1.353818e-06      9.59564e-07 2.395513e-06
```

Update 2: turning off standardization in `glmnet` gives:

```
> mylogit <- glmnet(X, y, family = "binomial", alpha = 0, standardize = F)
> coef(mylogit, s = 0.0025)
6 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     1
(Intercept)      -2.8180677693
gre               0.0034434192
gpa               0.0001882333
as.factor(rank)2  0.0001268816
as.factor(rank)3 -0.0002259491
as.factor(rank)4 -0.0002028832
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 10):

Dougal's answer is correct, you regularize the intercept in `sklearn` but not in R. Make sure you use `solver='newton-cg'` since default solver (`'liblinear'`) always regularizes the intercept.

cf https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6595

Comment: Setting `solver='newton-cg'` made the results from `sklearn` and `statsmodels` consistent. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

sklearn's logistic regression doesn't standardize the inputs by default, which changes the meaning of the $L_2$ regularization term; probably glmnet does.

Especially since your `gre` term is on such a larger scale than the other variables, this will change the relative costs of using the different variables for weights.

Note also that by including an explicit intercept term in the features, you're regularizing the intercept of the model. This is generally not done, since it means that your model is no longer covariant to shifting all the labels by a constant.

Comment: `glmnet` allows turning off standardization of the inputs, but the estimated coefficients are even more different, please see above. Also, I explicitly included intercept term in `sklearn` because `glmnet` includes one automatically, so this is to make sure that the input to both models are the same.

Comment: @hurrikale I think glmnet is probably not regularizing the intercept, but sklearn is. Drop the intercept column from `X` and pass `fit_intercept=True` (the default) to `LogisticRegression`. There's probably something else going on as well, though.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and yet got different sets of coefficient: `[-1.873, -0.0606, -1.175, -1.378, 0.00182, 0.2435]` for `sklearn` and `[-2.8181, 0.0001269, -0.0002259, -0.00020288, 0.00344, 0.000188]` for `glmnet` in order of `[Intercept, rank_2, rank_3, rank_4, gre, gpa]`. My concern is they differ both in magnitude and in positively/negatively affecting the probability, so without knowing why they differ, it is hard to choose one to interpret upon. And if there is by any chance a bug in one of the implementations, it is particularly important that I know which one to rely on.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `L1_wt=0` argument along with `alpha` in `fit_regularized()` call.

This code in `statsmodels`:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
res = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit_regularized(alpha=1/(y.shape[0]*C), L1_wt=0)
```

is equivalent to the following code from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C = C)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Hope it helps!