# Interpretation of odds ratio in a multivariable logistic model when dealing with categorical independent variables (more than 2 levels)

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, multivariate-analysis, odds-ratio

I have doubts concerning the correct interpretation of the odds ratio when I am dealing with categorical variables.
I try to explain it better:
Suppose having a multivariable logistic model (`glm`) with `gender` as one of the possible predictor. Then, I compute the odds ratio with the corresponding confidence intervals and then I can get the interpretation regarding my variable `gender`. For example, I can conclude that "Fixing the other variables, males are more likely to ... than females".
Now, suppose instead of a binary variable as `gender`, there is a variable with 4 levels (and none of them can be used as a reference one, because that has no meaning for my particular model). For example, `color` with 4 different values (*yellow*, *blue*, *green*,*red*).
My question is: what is the correct interpretation of the concept of odds ratio in this case, when I cannot compare the 4 different levels ?
Is there a way to compute the odds for all the possible levels?

Hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

To retain all levels of your categorical variable in the model output, you would need to drop the intercept from the model (i.e. `y ~ 0 + color`).

However, it rarely makes sense to fit a logistic regression without an intercept, because it implies that $P(Y=1 |\mathbf{x}=0)=0.5$ (which is often not the case).

Take a look a these questions & answers: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/260214/333765), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440242/statsmodels-logistic-regression-adding-intercept/440245#440245), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450332).

[This page](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_mult_logistic_model_without_intercept.htm) might also be helpful.