# logit GLM or traditional ML logistic regression for the probability of an event ocurring

Tags: regression, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, logistic

Sorry if the question is naive. I have a problem where i should predict the probability that someone will make a claim given a bunch of predictors. Let's say that the claim can take a range of values between 0-5 and it's highly skewed (gamma distribution).

Could someone tell me what is the benefit of using ML logistic regression over a GLM logit model or vice versa?

Thanks

Comment: How are GLM logistic regression and machine learning logistic regression different? // I’m not convinced that any kind of logistic regression is appropriate here. It sounds like you would want to do an ordinal regression to predict the value of the claim.

Comment: Does ML mean machine learning or maximum-likelihood here?

Comment: I said that i want to predict the probability that a claim will occur, not the value of the claim, thus I might convert it to a 0-1 problem. Yeah sorry I'm new to GLM and not sure yet if those two concepts are any different.. So sklern.LogisticRegression is the same as doing glm(family=binomial) from statsmodels?

Comment: @MichaelWebb machine learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "ML logistic regression" there is only one logistic regression. You could see some differences in the results of using logistic regression in, say, R vs scikit-learn because of using different optimization algorithms, also in [scikit-learn by default uses regularization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203740/logistic-regression-scikit-learn-vs-statsmodels), but those are technical details, while the algorithm remains the same.

Comment: I think either sklearn or statsmodels does not automatically use an intercept, too. That could make a huge difference.

Comment: @Dave I don't use statmodels, but scikit-learn by default uses intercept. It would be a strange and bad default not to use it.